# Does Nunit have a way of alerting me a test has failed when an If validation fails

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I have imported my Visual Studio Tests into Nunit Test Runner. The tests are set up using If Validations so the tests will run all the way through. The Tests are written in C# using Selenium Webdriver to drive them with an Nunit Framework. After I run the Test i see Pass but I see 0 Assertions which is correct because I never added them but I did add If's should I see an output of some kind to these failing like I would in Visual Studio?
I have goggled this and looked through Nunit documentation and Visual Studio and not found the exact answer.

Comment: what is an `If Validation`?  Can you post the code of one of your tests?

Comment: if (!driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).Text.Contains("sometext")) {Console.WriteLine("verifyTextsometext");}

Comment: ok, well, your statement above says if it does *not* contain `sometext` then output  `verifyTextsometext`.  I'm not sure why you're not just using assertions here though.  What goal are you trying to accomplish with these if statements?

Comment: if statements allow my tests to run completely through the test and give me an out put at the end showing me which of these if validations failed and which ones did not. Assertions fail the test immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to check a few cases within the same test. This is not a good idea. Here is [a good explanation](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/one-assertion-per-test-please.html) why.

If you rewrite tests with *the single-assert-per-test* approach then you will see it is OK to use assertions rather than validations. Assertions will work exactly how you do need:

- They don't interfere other cases (because the other cases are in the other tests)
- They alert NUnit that each validation is failed (because that is what alerts for).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alexander I understand that not everyone would use Nunit the way I am. The "good explanation" does not pertain to me. I am using Nunit as a Test runner and not as Unit Tests.

Comment: No matter how do you use NUnit. There is only one way to alert the validation is failed - is to fail the assert. And after assert is failed, test is interrupted. This is how NUnit (Test runner + framework) is designed. So checking just one validation (i.e. assert) per test is still godd choice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple assertions in a single test case. I have used this approach with MSTest (Not with NUnit). You can use try catch blocks in your test case. This will allow you to catch the failed Assertions and your test will continue. At the end of test case, you can check the number of failed assertions. If the count is greater than 1, you can forcefully fail that test case, else you can continue to your next test case. 
This approach is explained with example in this blog post. 
http://www.binaryclips.com/2016/03/coded-ui-test-testing-all-assertions-in.html